# Sharedprefrences value updates when a value is changed in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I want to understand the relation of Firebase with PreferenceManager. I have 4 Activity. Login, Register and Mainactivity and Second Activity.

When user register, his email, phone is saved in Firebase and also in PreferenceManager or user   with account when logs in. I retrieve the data from Firebase and save in PreferenceManager.

Next Time when user opens app, if he is logged in He will Be shown Mainactivity with One button to go SecondActivity where I display the PreferenceManager value I saved early.

When I click button and Second Activity Opens and values are displayed. But when I press back button and make any change in value of my firebase..Now when I press button and Second activity opens with new changed value.

I want to know whether firebase also sync the SharedPreferences values or not as I could find any related documentation.

Here is my code

My Login activity

```
private class t2 extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... strings) {

            String k = (strings[0]).replace('@','_');
            k = k.replace('.','_');
            Log.e("string[0] = ",k);
            dbreference.child("users").child(k).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String p = dataSnapshot.child("userPhoneno").getValue(String.class);
                    String n = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                    String u = dataSnapshot.child("userUniversity").getValue(String.class);
                    String e = loginid.getText().toString();

                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("phone",p).apply();
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("email",e).apply();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            publishProgress(strings[0]);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);

            i1.putExtra("showmail",fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            startActivity(i1);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

My Mainactivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    Button_One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    Button_One.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {

        case R.id.button:       
            startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
            break;

    }
}
```

In Second activity

```
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_mobile);
 class t3 extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            publishProgress();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);


            etEmail.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("email","Default email"));
            etMobile.setText(String.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("phone","Default phone")));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database does not do anything with Android SharedPreferences at all.

Answer (score 0):

In short : Firebase has nothing to do with your local Preference.

Why your preference been changed is because of this

```
dbreference.child("users").child(k).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   ....
                }
}
```

You save your data into preference in the `onDataChange(){}` block.

onDataChange means **every time the firebaseDB is changed**.

So no matter where you change your db(even from website), your pref will be updated if the activity is still alive.

Comment: Okay I understood now....when I close the app by pressing back button..the activity are still alive i.e Loginactivity and when I change any value in Firebase then immediately the change appears in app also....Untill I kill the app and restart again. Then If user is logged in then LoginActivity will not start ...and now when I press button to open SecondActivity the chnages won't appear ..is that right?

Comment: Almost right: Even it's killed, it will read firebase to pref again next time you create the Activity.

Comment: If you don't want that, you should use some logic to prevent that. maybe something like `if(!pref.somevalue!=null)...`

Comment: Yes I checked..now...when I kill the app and now when I open my app..it launches Mainactivity and when I click button to go to next activity..same value appears and no any value changed in Firebase do not appear. I understood very well now. Thank @Wesely and Everyone.

Comment: No I want to apply this part but though I followed some tutorials...I was not getting the part why it is showing the changed value ..since Firebase don't change any value saved in Sharedprefrences..so I wanted to understand the proeblem...but yes I want to show the updated value to user in my app.....!!

Answer (score 0):

It's your code that sets values in preference manager. On changing anything in firebase ,the firebase database change listener attached in app  code also gets invoked and at that place you are saving the values in prefrences.